# Add in to selected value in multiselect picklist

Tags: trigger, update, multi-select

I try to wriht trigger on update the parent account object from Issue__c. So any time the Issue__c will meet criteria it will update certain fields:

```
trigger CaseLastStatusChange on Issues__c (after update) {

    Map<Id, Account> parentAccs = new Map<Id, Account>();
    Map<Id, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rt_map = 
        Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Issues__c').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();
    List<id> listIds = new List<Id>();    
    for(Issues__c iss : Trigger.new){
        listIds.add(iss.Account__c);
    }            
    parentAccs = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN :listIds]);

    for(Issues__c issup : Trigger.new) {
        Account ParAcc = parentAccs.get(issup.Account__c);
        if(rt_map.get(issup.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('Onboarding') && 
            issup.Status__c == 'KYC Finalized' && 
            issup.Client_Setup_with__c == 'BCS UK'){

            ParAcc.KYC_Status_UK__c = 'Active';
            ParAcc.Country_of_Incorporation_Nationality__c 
                = issup.Country_of_Incorporation__c;
            ParAcc.Client_Category_UK__c = issup.Client_Category__c;

            //This is my multiselect field
            ParAcc.Account_Types_with_UK__c = OLD_VALUE+';'+issup.Account_Type__c;

            ParAcc.Client_regulated__c = issup.Client_regulated__c;
            ParAcc.Regulator__c = issup.Regulator__c;
            ParAcc.AML_Risk_level__c = issup.AML_Risk_level__c;
            ParAcc.Street__c = issup.Reg_Address_Line_1__c;
            ParAcc.City__c = issup.Reg_Address_City__c;
            ParAcc.ZIP_Code__c = issup.Reg_Address_ZIP_Code__c;
            ParAcc.Country__c = issup.Reg_Address_Country__c;
            ParAcc.Reg_Code_Assigned_by_Regulator__c = issup.Reg_Code_Assigned_by_Regulator__c;
            ParAcc.Registration_Code__c = issup.Reg_code_passport_details__c;
            ParAcc.Date_of_incorporation__c = issup.Date_of_incorporation__c;
            ParAcc.LEI_Code__c = issup.LEI_Code__c;
            ParAcc.SWIFT_Code__c = issup.SWIFT_Code__c;
            ParAcc.Company_Website__c = issup.Company_Website__c;
        }
    }    
    update parentAccs.values();
}
```

And I want to do some thing like this: OLD_VALUE+';'+dynamic issup.Account_Type__c value at any time it will meet the criteria. Please suggest me how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take this approach which avoids duplicates if you only ever want to add values:

```
Map<Id, Account> parentAccs = new Map<Id, Account>([
        SELECT Id, Account_Types_with_UK__c
        FROM Account
        WHERE ID IN :listIds
        ]);
for (Issues__c issup : Trigger.new) {
    Account parAcc = parentAccs.get(issup.Account__c);
    if (...) {
        if (!String.isEmpty(issup.Account_Type__c)) {
            Set<String> typesSet = !String.isEmpty(parAcc.Account_Types_with_UK__c)
                    ? new Set<String>(parAcc.Account_Types_with_UK__c.split(';'))
                    : new Set<String>();
            typesSet.add(issup.Account_Type__c);
            List<String> typesList = new List<String>(typesSet);
            typesList.sort();
            parAcc.Account_Types_with_UK__c = String.join(typesList, ';');
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

But this sort of logic can't handle the case of the last instance of a specific `issup.Account_Type__c` under an `Account` being changed and so correctly removed from the `parAcc.Account_Types_with_UK__c` collection. Handling that requires all the child `Issues__c` of the `Account`s to be requeried - I suggest that approach.